# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fireStaff, Line 17 Incorrect syntax near ';'

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to delete a staff member with the trigger below but when I try to run it I'm getting the error :

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fireStaff, Line 17 [Batch Start
>   Line 255] Incorrect syntax near ';'.

```
CREATE TRIGGER fireStaff
ON dbo.Staff
FOR DELETE
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT OFF;
        DECLARE @id_s INT ,
                @sal INT;

        SELECT @id_s = STAFF_ID
        FROM   deleted;
        SELECT @sal = salary
        FROM   deleted;

        IF @sal > 7000
            BEGIN
                RAISERROR(
                    'Trigger has been stopped, not allowed to 
                     delete a worker who earns salary over 7000.' ,
                    16 ,
                    1);
                ROLLBACK;
            END;
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                PRINT 'Staff name "' + CAST(@id_s AS NVARCHAR(20))
                      + '" was  deleted from the database.';
            END;


GO
```

where do I missing something?

Comment: You're missing an `END;` at the end (before `GO`) for a start, indending your code properly would have shown you that.

Comment: big troubles for some simple answers for StackOverflow, thank you that solved.

Comment: i updated your code which highlights the missing code a bit better

Comment: Your trigger has a MAJOR flaw. It assumes that there will only ever be a single row in deleted. Triggers in sql server fire once per operation, not once per row. Your trigger needs to handle multiple rows.

Comment: nice catch @SeanLange, i didn't look past the simple error message!

Comment: I know but this is just for a small school project if it works even for a one single row I believe the teacher will be accepted.

Comment: Even for a school project you should avoid the habit of "good enough for now". That mentality will follow you into the work place and it is like cancer for an IT department. And you might look a bit closer at your logic in the else. I don't think you want to say that Staff name 19283 was deleted. Pretty sure you want their name. :) And honestly PRINT in a trigger is useless for anything other than debugging.

Comment: I've updated my answer, per @SeanLange 's observation. It works for "one row is ok" is not the attitude you should have here. If you had a car accident, and 4 people died, but 1 didn't because that seat belt worked and the other didn't, you wouldn't let the car manufacturer off would you? It's all in the detail. (a bit extreme, yes, but regardless of level, you should be ensuring your work is correct for everything, no just some of the time).

Comment: you guys are right, sorry for my behavior in the comment above, thank you for your answers a lot :)

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about, CemAtes. @SeanLange points out a valid valid point that "it'll do" or "good enough for now" is a mentality that is awful for the IT community. The fact that you've accepted that the correct way is to ensure you handle more than one row at a time already puts you on the right path. Just keep on making sure that you continue using complete answers, and not short cuts and you'll see the benefit very quickly. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an `END`. if you indent properly, it becomes apparent:

```
CREATE TRIGGER fireStaff
ON DBO.STAFF
FOR DELETE AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    DECLARE @id_s INT, @sal INT;

    SELECT @id_s = STAFF_ID FROM deleted;
    SELECT @sal = salary FROM deleted;

    IF @sal>7000 BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Trigger has been stopped, not allowed to delete a worker who earns salary over 7000.',16,1); ROLLBACK;
    END;
    ELSE BEGIN
        PRINT 'Staff name "'+ Cast(@id_s as nvarchar(20))+'" was  deleted from the database.';
    END;
-- END GOES HERE
GO
```

As per Sean's comment, yes, this "fails" if you delete multiple Staff Members. Thus, the following would solve the issue:

```
CREATE TRIGGER fireStaff
ON DBO.STAFF
FOR DELETE AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    --DECLARE @id_s INT, @sal INT;

    --SELECT @id_s = STAFF_ID FROM deleted;
    --SELECT @sal = salary FROM deleted;

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM deleted WHERE salary >7000) > 0 BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Trigger has been stopped, not allowed to delete a worker who earns salary over 7000.',16,1);
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
    ELSE BEGIN
        PRINT 'Staff member(s) were deleted from the database.';
    END;
END;
GO
```

If you really *need* the staff member(s) names in there, we can do something.

Note, that this will cancel the whole transaction as well though, so if one staff member had a salary of 5000, and the other 10000, neither would be deleted. More precise detail might be, therefore, required on your needs.

Comment: @Tanner You can't, however, format for proper indenting in a comment, which was a main point.

Comment: The bigger issue is the scalar variables and the assumption of only a single row in deleted.

Comment: Very good point, @SeanLange, hadn't noticed either. Will update.